# Fields interfering with method resolution for Scala Dynamic trait?

Tags: scala, dynamic, scalac

As my first foray into Dynamic Scala land, I thought that I'd try accessing bean properties via applyDynamic.

My first very rough cut is

```
trait BeanProperties extends Dynamic {
  def applyDynamic(name: String)(args: Any*) = {
    if (args.length == 0)
      PropertyUtils.getProperty(this, name)
    else
      null
  }
}
```

so that

```
val bean = new JTextField("text") with BeanProperties
bean.getText should equal("text")
bean.text should equal("text")
```

so far so good! But when I try

```
bean.background should equal(bean.getBackground)
```

the compiler complains, trying instead to give access to the field named background rather than synthesizing a method.

```
variable background in class Component cannot be accessed in javax.swing.JTextField with BeanPropertiesTest.this.BeanProperties
```

Is this by design, an oversight, or something that is planned to be fixed?

Comment: Quite a bit of lurking interest it seems, but no one has any thoughts - and the Scala mailing lists are curiously silent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, I proposed a fix for this https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/98

If it is accepted, it will indeed be fixed by the time Dynamic comes out of -Xexperimental.

Answer (score 0):

Answer on the Scala-Lang mailing list from Martin Odersky

> I think this should be fixed by the time Dynamic comes out of -Xexperimental.